# JMockit: expectations on non-mock objects, or, mock objects with more behavior

Tags: jmockit

I am using the class below in a test to take the place of the 'real' `Requestor`. (The real one does HTTP.) Note that the method in here has `void` for return type, but it has behavior to mock; it calls back on the callback. I wish that I could write expectations on the method here so that I don't need to write JUnit asserts on counters and such. But I don't see how; I don't see how this can be an `@Mock`, since I'm not substituting for some other live object, and I don't see how to use a delegate for a function that returns `void`. Is there a way?

```
    private static class TrivialRequestor implements Requestor {

    private final boolean error;
    private final int returnedQueueDepth;

    TrivialRequestor(boolean error, int returnedQueueDepth) {
        this.error = error;
        this.returnedQueueDepth = returnedQueueDepth;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatch(Ticket ticket, FutureCallback<RequestorResult> callback) {
        if (error) {
            callback.onFailure(new Exception("You asked for it"));
        } else {
            callback.onSuccess(new RequestorResult(ticket, returnedQueueDepth));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `Delegate` can be used for a `void` method just the same as a non-void one; it's the same syntax.

Comment: How about an answer with an example? Does one really write `result = new Delegate...` even when the mocked method returns void?

Comment: Any example with `result = new Delegate() ...` is valid; note that `result` is not the same as "return value" (which is just one of three kinds of results).

Comment: I'm usually a fairly good doc reader, and none of this was clear to me from the doc. So, I repeat, I think you'd be doing the internet a favor if you typed in an answer here, complete with one (or three?) examples.

Comment: Well, the [API doc for `result`](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Expectations.html#result) does say that "Results that depend on some programming logic can be provided through a Delegate object assigned to the field. This applies to void and non-void methods, as well as to constructors."